# Should BlockingCollection.TryTake(object,TimeSpan) return immediately on new data?

Tags: c#, performance, blockingcollection

I am trying to ascertain why performance on my blocking collection appears slow. A simple version of my code is illustrated in the question further below.

My question here is if BlockingCollection.TryTake(object,TimeSpan) returns immediately on new data?

```
TimeSpan gridNextTS = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

if (trPipe.TryTake(out tr, gridNextTS) == false)
```

From my testing it appears that data is NOT returned immediately. Does that seems likely desired behaviour or am I using it incorrectly?

Detail of code previous question:

[Consumer/Producer with BlockingCollection appears slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711125/consumer-producer-with-blockingcollection-appears-slow)

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately"? (A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would really help.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concise benchmark shows that `BlockingCollection<T>` does, in fact, perform the handover pretty swiftly regardless of the timeout value supplied to `TryTake`.

```
public async Task BlockingCollectionPerformance()
{
    using (var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>())
    {
        var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var i = 0;

            while (collection.TryTake(out i, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
            {
                Debug.Print(i.ToString());
            }
        });

        var producer = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    collection.Add(i);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                collection.CompleteAdding();
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
    }
}
```

The above completes in ~3 ms on my box.

To be more specific though, `TryTake` returns quickly whenever an item is added to the collection (and `TryTake` returns `true`), *or* when you call `CompleteAdding` on the blocking collection (in which case there is no point in waiting out the timeout, and `TryTake` returns `false`). It *is* possible to shoot yourself in the foot by keeping the consumer blocked longer than necessary if you never call `CompleteAdding` in which case `TryTake` will have to wait out the full timeout length before returning `false`.

Comment: Apologies for the `TryAdd`s in the original version: that was a typo.

Comment: I get hundreds of thousands of Add events every day. Should I call CompleteAdding after each?

Comment: @ManInMoon, only if you use hundreds of thousands of blocking collections (which you probably don't). CompleteAdding needs to be called once - when you're done with the collection and won't ever add to it again. The main point is - blocking collection is fast (for what it does), so look for your bottleneck elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Blockage was elsewhere. I am not calling CompleteAdding at all ,because the Collection is constantly updated during the day. You are correct, the footprint is very small and I can run through several million Add/TryTake cycles in a very short period. Many thanks

Comment: @ManInMoon, glad to hear you worked it out in the end.